# Ansible: How to inform a python script about the outcome of a task?

Tags: python, ansible

I have simple playbook to fetch and copy files from a share to remote windows clients:

```
- name: Test chocolatey module
  hosts: win_clones
  vars_files:
  - /fullpath/hosts_vars
  tasks:
    - name: Fetching and copying the file on the client ...
      win_get_url:
        url: 'ftp://172.20.0.5/choco-repo/{{ item }}'
        dest: 'C:\Test\{{ item }}'
      with_items: "{{ clients[machine].to_install }}"
```

I run this play from a python script using subprocess:

```
for i in clients:
    machine = "machine="
    limit = "--limit="
    an2 = subprocess.Popen(["ansible-playbook", "fetch.yml","-e", machine+i, limit+i], cwd='/home/diego/work/gitl_repo/ansible-software-deployment')
    an2.wait()
```

When a task fails for whatever reason I can see that in my terminal:

```
TASK [Fetching and copying the file on the client ...] *************************
failed: [cl1] (item=banana) => {"failed": true, "item": "banana", "msg": "Error downloading ftp://172.20.0.5/.....
```

Is it possible to pass this information to my python script? In other words, How could I tell python about the outcome of a certain task, i.e. if it failed or if it went through. Thanks

Comment: Any reason you are not using the [ansible python api](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_api.html)?

Comment: I am running ansible 2.1.0.0 and I found the doc of ansible python api for this version very lacking of information, i.e. very easy to run the subprocess not so for the api..

Comment: @BurhanKhalid could you show me how to use the api for what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `stdout_callback = json` via [configuration](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#stdout-callback) file or env variable `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK`.
`ansible-playbook` will print huge json file with execution result to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the playbook from the Python API (though it's more code and Ansible doesn't officially support it for external callers).  Use the example from [Python API 2.0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_api.html#python-api-2-0) as a baseline, and instead of loading a play, load a playbook:

```
from ansible.playbook import Playbook

playbook = Playbook(loader).load('fetch.yml' loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager)
```

Then substitute

```
result = tqm.run(play)
```

for this

```
for play in playbook.get_plays():
    result = tqm.run(play)
```

You'll need some adaptation to get it to iterate multiple times per your for loop above, but this is the framework.

Comment: I cannot use loader. It says loader not found. If I inspect Playbook by doing dir(Playbook) in ipython `loader` does not appear in the list. It does appear: `get_loader` I tried to use your syntax with the latter but it is not working...any idea why? thanks for your help